# React Setting State From Data Recieved In Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to get some data from my server with an AJAX call that looks like

```
fetch_reviews() {
    var scraper_url = this.props.thing.text
    var all_the_data = $.get({
      url: window.location.origin+'/fetch_review_data', 
      data: {scraper_url: scraper_url}
    }).success(function(data){
      this.state.allReviews = data
    });
  }
```

onle I keep getting the error "cannot read property *allReviews* of undefined"

How can I set the state of *allReviews* from inside the `success` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)(if you use ES2015) or [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in order to set `this` that will refer to your Component object, because now `this` refers to global scope(`window` or `undefined` if you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)),

```
// ...
.success((data) => {
   this.setState({ allReviews: data })
});
```

or

```
// ...
.success(function (data) {
   this.setState({ allReviews: data })
}.bind(this));
```

also if you need set new state in React you must use [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) method

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` changes to `$.get` execution scope while your state is attached to react's execution scope which is not accessible inside your fetch. So hold your `this` in a variable...

```
fetch_reviews() {
        var scraper_url = this.props.thing.text;
        var that = this; // hold this in another variable
        var all_the_data = $.get({
          url: window.location.origin+'/fetch_review_data', 
          data: {scraper_url: scraper_url}
        }).success(function(data){
          that.setState({allReviews : data });
        });
      }
```